# using .NET 4.5 HttpClient in ASP.NET Web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I Want to use .NET 4.5 HttpClient class in ASP.NET Web Form.
I read in the **C# 5.0 in a NutShell** Book (page 663):

> Unlike with WebClient, to get the best performance with HttpClient, you must reuse same instance (otherwise things such as DNS resolution
>   may be unnecessarily repeated.) HttpClient permits concurrent
>   operations, . . .

In our ASP.NET web Form website ,we need to connect to another website.
I have created an instance of HttpClient in the **Application** property to use a single instance in all requests.
in Global.asax something like this is written:

```
Application.Add("MateCatWorker", new HttpClient());
```

My question is that:Is it a good practice?

Comment: why do you think it wouldn't be good practice?

Comment: because: when I lunched our web site with above practice, I encounter into 2 kind of errors from our clients that I cannot understand why.

Comment: so what did you try to fix it?  Also, just because something doesn't work doesn't mean its not best practice, it could just be a poor implementation of the practice.

Comment: This might be of your interest: http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: I searched for these errors in the internet. but I cannot find an absolute solution.

Comment: @EhsanAbidi what errors? You haven't posted any error messages or described any problem. You posted a *very* strange `Application.Add` line - what's the point of reusing an *empty* HttpClient? You'd still have to repeat DNS resolution for every single absolute URL!

Comment: The books and refrences which I read, does not mentioned to add some config to an HttpClient to benefi from re-using same instance. but from your answer, I think it is a good idea to write the url in the new statement. also I go these 2 error:1- A task was canceled.2-Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [HttpClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5) on MSDN these methods are thread-safe:

> - CancelPendingRequests
> - DeleteAsyn
> - GetAsync
> - GetByteArrayAsync
> - GetStreamAsync
> - GetStringAsync
> - PostAsync
> - PutAsync
> - SendAsync
>
> HttpClient **is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout**
>   **the life of an application**. Instantiating an HttpClient class for
>   every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy
>   loads. This will result in SocketException errors. Below is an example
>   using HttpClient correctly.

And I recommend not to store the `HttpClient` into `Application`, I'm not a fan of singleton but create a singleton class for that is much more better.

```
public class GoodHttpClient
{
    // OK
    private static readonly _httpClient HttpClient;

    static GoodHttpClient()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET WF doesn't use controllers, also, saving the variable in a page is not very useful since you generally just have one point of calling.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice: no, not in my opinion. Note that the application context might be synced between instances in a web farm, so I wouldn't really use that to store such variable.

Does it work? Yes, if you use one of the async methods mentioned in the remarks section of [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5), since those are safe to use in multiple threads:

- `CancelPendingRequests`
- `DeleteAsync`
- `GetAsync`
- `GetByteArrayAsync`
- `GetStreamAsync`
- `GetStringAsync`
- `PostAsync`
- `PutAsync`
- `SendAsync`

Honestly, I would not worry too much about it. If you run calls in a tight loop, reuse the same object. If not, don't reuse it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what does this sentence means: 'Note that the application context might be synced between instances in a web farm'

Comment: If you have the same application running in a web farm it shares the application context. But that might be too high-end for your current question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think he doesn't use any load-balancer, it's just a single web server.

Comment: @EhsanAbidi are these answers sufficient for you or do you need more information from us?

Comment: Feel free to accept either of the answers then. Also review your old posts and see if those answers were sufficient to you. You can accept an answer by checking the checkmark before the answer.

Comment: those async calls will all deadlock when used in asp.net web forms

Answer (score 0):

All HttpClient methods are async and will deadlock when used in ASP.NET web forms.

Microsoft for some reason didn't create them synchronous.